# How to $inject into Angular class w/ES6

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6

Using Angular 1.4 with ES6/7 and Babel, I can successfully inject parameters into a class named Controller with this code after the class block:

```
class Controller {
    constructor($scope, $state, $window) {...}
    ...
}
Controller.$inject = ["$scope", "$state", "$window"]
```

However, it would be cleaner to see the inject parameters right above the constructor.  I've seen other people use static $inject, but I get an error.  Here's what I'm attempting:

```
class Controller {
    static $inject = ["$scope", "$state", "$window"]
    constructor($scope, $state, $window) {...}
    ...
}
```

Why does that cause this error?  It seems to work for other people.

```
Unexpected token (2:11)
  1 | class Controller {
  2 |     static $inject = ["$scope", "$state", "$window"]
    |  
              ^
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is an experimental proposed syntax. In Babel, you'd have to enable `es7.classProperties`. Pass

```
optional: ['es7.classProperties']
```

to babel. The exact method depends on how you are transpiling.

If you wanted to do standard ES6, you could also do

```
static get $inject(){ return ["$scope", "$state", "$window"]; }
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I was missing.  I added the following to gulp and now it works.
`.transform(babelify.configure({
                optional: ["es7.classProperties"]
            }))`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be use `$injector.annotate(fn)`, which Angular uses for dependency injection, and which allows you to get arguments of the function you pass to it. You could utilize it to get the names of all `constructor()` parameters, and retrieve them using `$injector.get()`.

Here's a [link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37330930/2066118) in another thread, and a direct [link to a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maciejgurban/d7jm0L2r/) with a demo.