# How to do dependency injection in AngularJs using ES6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, yeoman

I am using yeoman angular-fullstack boilerplate.

```
'use strict';

class SignupController {
    // Logic for signup.
}

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('SignupController', SignupController);
```

How can i do dependency injection for particular controller ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to $inject into Angular class w/ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627753/how-to-inject-into-angular-class-w-es6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angular-fullstack generator seems to include [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) which generates the injection code for you.
You might be able to do something like:

```
class Service {
  /* @ngInject */
  constructor($scope, $state) {

  }
}
```