# AngularJS use custom filter in javascript file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, ecmascript-6

Pretty new to angularjs, this is my struggle :

```
//my-filter.filter.js

function myFilter($filter){
    return filter(input){
        return $filter('currency')(input, 'X');;
    }
}

myFilter.$inject = ['$filter'];

export default myFilter;
```

And :

```
//my-component.component.js

class MyComponentController {
    constructor(currencyFilter){
        this.currencyFilter = currencyFilter;
    }

    $onChanges(changes) {
        this.message = changes.data.message;

        this.message = this.currencyFilter(this.message);
    }

    ...
}
```

And :

```
.filter('bsMyFilter', myFilter);
```

What I want to achieve is inside `my-component.component.js` not to use the default angular currencyFilter, but instead to use myFilter. Is this possible and how ? Thx

Comment: I think you need to change your filter to: `app.filter('myFilter', function(){ ... });` then it will be automatically part of `$filter`, which is the only thing that you need to inject into your component: `constructor($filter){...` and then use it with `this.message = $filter('myFilter')(this.message);` (could be wrong somewhere with ES6 syntax, _adjust accordingly_)

Comment: I have something like .filter('bsMyFilter', myFilter); I don't know if I can change this, is there any other way to inject the filter ? How ?

Comment: (I would avoid ES6 altogether) Here is everything about injections: [`$injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector), and here is a possible injection for ES6 classes: [`$injector.annotate(fn)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529518/automatically-set-arguments-as-instance-properties-in-es6/37330930#37330930)

Comment: This is what I got, I have to work with this. Is there any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

inject `$filter`, `$filter('bsMyFilter')` is you filter. 
At least in angular 1.6 - but I doupt they change it.

Note: if you not gonna use it in templates - just create factory.