# ECMAScript proposal for constructor parameter properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-next

In TypeScript, there is convenient syntax, [constructor parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties):

```
constructor(a, public b, private _c) {}
```

Which is syntactic sugar for:

```
constructor(a, b, _c) {
  this.b = b;
  this._c = _c;
}
```

Considering that there are ECMAScript proposals for other features that previously were specific to TypeScript like [class fields and their visibility](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), it would be reasonable to get parameter properties, too.

Are there proposals or other initiatives for constructor parameter properties in ECMAScript? Are there Babel transforms that support this or similar syntactic sugar?

I weren't able to find any but I assume that different terminology could be used for same functionality.

Comment: I really wish there were, I miss that from coffeescript as well.

Comment: @JaredSmith True, that's one of few reasons why I'd go with TS as a transpiler of choice (setting aside types). Just had an answer on related question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51958460/3731501 and got curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there proposals or other initiatives for constructor parameter properties in ECMAScript?

No.

> Are there Babel transforms that support this or similar syntactic sugar?

Use `typescript` transform with babel : https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-typescript.html

OR

Just use `typescript` by itself as that provides the transform

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about plugin-transform-typescript. Makes everything a bit simpler.